# How to set the desktop background to a solid color programmatically

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

How can you set the desktop background to a solid color programmatically in python?

The reason I want this is to make myself a utility which changes the background color depending on which of several virtual desktops I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to call `SystemParametersInfo` SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER with an empty string to remove the wallpaper and then call [`SetSysColors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsyscolors) to change the desktop color. You probably need ctypes to do this in Python.

If you want to persist the change after log-off you also need to write the color to the registry.

Comment: On older versions of Windows you also need to turn off the pattern but pattern support was removed at some point and no longer relevant. Pattern works in XP but not in 10, not sure when it was removed, Vista perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

To change windows desktop wallpaper what we normally do is right click on the desktop and go properties and so on. But we can do the same by editing registry key using reg command from command line. The command is given below.

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  wallpaper_path /f
```

For example to set the image E:\photos\image1.bmp as the wall paper we need to run the command as below.

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d E:\photos\image1.bmp /f
```

After editing the registry key we need to run the below command to make the change take effect immediately.

```
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Note

> this method works only for bmp images. If you have .jpg or .jpeg
> images you can’t set them as wallpaper from command line. You can use
> the Desktop settings UI to set a .jpg or .jpeg file as wallpaper.

so now you can use `os` or `subprocess` to run `cmd` then you can set `desktop background`

This page may also help you: [How do I set the desktop background on Windows from a script?](https://superuser.com/questions/277805/how-do-i-set-the-desktop-background-on-windows-from-a-script)

**Update**

The background is stored in the registry. There are a few different ways to set it. But there several ways to set a registry value via the command line.

To set the background to a specific color you need to unset any wallpaers, and set the color.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background = 'r g b'
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper = ''
```

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because it is useful and I can indeed make solid color bitmaps to do the job... but I'm curious why you've chosen to set an image - is setting a solid color directly much harder?

Comment: Because you may not be able to find the design you want, you can add your own custom photo

Comment: Anyway, I corrected my answer

Comment: As an experiment I just changed HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background directly in regedit, then I typed RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters into a command prompt - no change of color. I noticed that in this page: https://superuser.com/questions/277805/how-do-i-set-the-desktop-background-on-windows-from-a-script you see Pater Hahndorf makes a similar comment. BTW, I'm using windows 10 if that's of any consequence.

Comment: Calling UpdatePerUserSystemParameters  with rundll32 is a horrible incorrect hack