# Python: how to get Windows desktop background color

Tags: python, desktop, pywin32

Context: on my office PC there is apllied corporate policy -> standard company picture on desktop wallpaper. Picture is too bright; I switch it off to more dark backgroubd color, do it by manually running the script several times per day.

Aim: automate this operation with Python

1. once per some time
2. check some desktop background pixel
3. if it color is not equal to my preference
4. then apply this color to desktop background

I have an issue with p. 2. I found following code for picking up pixel color on desktop:

```
    def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
        import win32gui     # pip install pywin32

        #i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.FindWindow('SysListView32', None)

        i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
        long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
        i_colour = int(long_colour)
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(i_desktop_window_id, i_desktop_window_dc)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)

print(get_pixel_colour(100, 5))
```

It works.
At the same time it picks up color from the foreground window:
if there is some app window over pixel(100, 5) then color will be grabbed from this window, not from desktop background.

Any ideas how to get desktop background color even then there is some other app is not top ?

Comment: It's a nice little project. I'm assuming the script would be quite lightweight - why not just have it set the preferred color without checking if it's already applied? This is of course just a suggestion for an easier solution and will take the fun factor out of figuring this hurdle.

Comment: Is the picture changing? If not can't you just snapshot it and use fixed data?

Comment: @LTJ , you are right, that this "project" is an exercise for learning Python )
I'm going to check pixel color every 1 second ... to apply background change with this time period would be too often.

Comment: @matszwecja the picture changing, every 30-60 minutes.
If I remover it (change desktop backgroynd), then it'll be moved back by windows domain police [or admins script, or whatever].

Comment: sorry for lot of misspelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grabbing a pixel value directly from what is displayed on the screen will be a problematic solution for a script running in the background. Instead I'd try to get the actual value of the wallpaper image pixel. You can get the path to currently set wallpaper using `SystemParametersInfoA`.

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14
SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x73
buf_size = 200
path = ctypes.create_string_buffer(buf_size)
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, buf_size, path , buf_size)
print(path.value)
```

With this path you can load the actual image, check its brightness or whatever value you are interested in, and edit according to your wishes. You could use `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` then to set the background to edited image or whatever else you want.

Comment: Thanks, thats it. Also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097284/how-to-set-the-desktop-background-to-a-solid-color-programmatically): check `path` and if it has value then set it to empty. Already implemented, it works.

Comment: I'd also suggest contacting people responsible for that policy and let them know the issue. The script might not be a viable solution long-term if the company *requires* you to have specific background, but they might change it if there are comfort issues.

Comment: there is no issue with policy: the unified background has been made by corporate brand book [I suppose] for front-end employees. For back-office it is a kind of "legacy" )

Comment: @AndreyK since you have to run a script to ignore it, I'd say there IS an issue. But whatever honestly.